# Class variables not updating

Tags: java

I have not programmed in Java in a while, I tried to figure this out but could not.

When I declare a class variable then try to update it and print it, the variable does not change from null. Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong. Here is the code I typed up to test this. When I call the method and print it that gets the right variable but when just calling the class variable it is still set to 0. Thank you for you help

```
package test;

public class method {

    public static int z  ;

    public method(){

    }

    public static void setZ(int z){
        method.z = z;
    }

    public static int getZ(){
        return method.z;
    }

    public static int add(int z){
        method.z = 15;
        return method.z;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(z);
    }
}
```

Comment: z is a class valriable and every object will be by default null and primitives like int,long will be 0. When you call that method,you are assiging a value to z ,if not z is automatically assigned to 0 as it is int.

Comment: Where is actually your method call? You just print the default value of an int variable which is 0 in this case.

Comment: You never call any (class) method, so z is 0. Try `method.setZ(10)` before printing for example.

Comment: call "add()" before printing

Answer (score 3):

you need method call before print statement

```
package test;

public class method {

    public static int z  ;

    public method(){

    }

    public static void setZ(int z){
        method.z = z;
    }

    public static int getZ(){
        return method.z;
    }

    public static int add(int z){
        method.z = 15;
        return method.z;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        setZ(10);
        System.out.println(z);
    }
}
```